# Problem installing Sitefinity 4 custom module

Tags: module, sitefinity-4

I'm posting this here since I didn't get any support from the sitefinity forum.

I created a new SiteFinity 4.0 project and added the Meeting module from the [Intranet Starter Kit](http://www.sitefinity.com/starter-kits/intranet.aspx). Here's what I did:

1. Added reference to **Telerik.Sitefinity.StarterKit.Intranet.Meetings.dll**
2. Registered the module ([image: screenshot])
3. Registered the widget

The widget appears in the toolbox under the Custom section but I dont see the Meeting link under the Content top menu.

Am I missing something? Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

when registering the module, try setting the StartupType to OnApplicationStart. then after adding the module, restart your website by saving the web.config. This restarts the Sitefinity application and causes the module to be installed.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Yap changed the StartupType but how do I restart the website? Saving the web.config? I'm not sure I understand what you want me to do exactly with the web.config. Should I just open it in VS and hit save?

Comment: that's exactly right, open the web.config file in visual studio (or notepad) add a space then delete it (so it's modified) then save it. this will force your website to restart and the module should then install.

Comment: Ok I've restarted the website but I dont see the Meetings module in the Content menu but I see my other custom module. The following two entries are present in the SystemConfig.config under App_Data/SiteFinity/Configuration


`<add title="Meetings" description="" resourceClassId="" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.StarterKit.Intranet.Meetings.MeetingsModule" startupType="OnApplicationStart" version="1.0.0.0" name="Meetings" />
        <add title="Jobs" description="" resourceClassId="" type="Jobs.Jobs_Module" startupType="OnApplicationStart" version="1.0.0.0" name="Jobs" />`